# CPP MQTT Broker code not working

Tags: c++, mqtt, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I need to use [mqtt broker](http://mosquitto.org/) in a project of mine. But i felt there is a huge lack of documentation. Some of the available example codes i found didn't really work for me. Followed this [example](http://www.disk91.com/2013/technology/programming/mosquitto-c-sample-code-to-publish-message/), but got compilation error

```
[subho@localhost] taboo $  g++ mqtt.cpp -o a
/tmp/ccg9xcFV.o: In function `myMosq::myMosq(char const*, char const*, char const*, int)':
mqtt.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::mosquittopp(char const*, bool)'
mqtt.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `mosqpp::lib_init()'
mqtt.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::connect_async(char const*, int, int)'
mqtt.cpp:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::loop_start()'
mqtt.cpp:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::~mosquittopp()'
/tmp/ccg9xcFV.o: In function `myMosq::~myMosq()':
mqtt.cpp:(.text+0xf5): undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::loop_stop(bool)'
mqtt.cpp:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `mosqpp::lib_cleanup()'
mqtt.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::~mosquittopp()'
mqtt.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::~mosquittopp()'
/tmp/ccg9xcFV.o: In function `myMosq::send_message(char const*)':
mqtt.cpp:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::publish(int*, char const*, int, void const*, int, bool)'
/tmp/ccg9xcFV.o:(.rodata._ZTI6myMosq[_ZTI6myMosq]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for mosqpp::mosquittopp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Also tried to look into the sample codes given in the [mqtt archive](http://mosquitto.org/download/) but make command failed to compile them. So tried to compile the sample files separately which succeeded but while running it gives [buffer overflow](http://ur1.ca/jygy8) and mosquito terminal output is

```
[subho@localhost] Web_App $ (master) mosquitto
1426996368: mosquitto version 1.3.5 (build date 2014-10-16 10:32:53+0000) starting
1426996368: Using default config.
1426996368: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1426996368: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1426996369: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1426996369: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as tempconv (c1, k60).
1426996369: Socket error on client tempconv, disconnecting.
1426997037: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1426997037: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as tempconv (c1, k60).
1426997037: Socket error on client tempconv, disconnecting.
1426997314: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1426997314: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as tempconv (c1, k60).
1426997314: Socket error on client tempconv, disconnecting.
```

It would be great if somebody has worked with mqtt before and can share a basic code. Thanks.
I have pushed all the files i tried in github, you can have a look [here](https://github.com/Ghost-script/MQTT-CPP-Sample).

Comment: I'm playing with Mosquitto as well and managed to make the examples work through the following steps:

- installed the Ubuntu repository version of the broker as described in the [Mosquitto download page](http://mosquitto.org/download/)
- downloaded the mosquitto source code and launched the `make` on the  uncompressed folder
- launched `make` inside the tempcov example folder

For me the example compiled and actually worked with the broker installed separately.

Comment: However the other [example](http://www.disk91.com/2013/technology/programming/mosquitto-c-sample-code-to-publish-message/) you mentioned is compiling but not working for me. I believe there's an issue on `connect_async` as I'm getting a return code != from 0 when trying to connect to the broker...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem from time to time. Maybe the late answer helps another one, too. Ubuntu has a rather old version of mosquitto. In the meantime it became an eclipse project and some things changed.

This problem occurs, if the mosquitto package of a linux distribution is installed, where the library files go into /usr/lib. For having the header files the source code has to be downloaded and if make install is called, the new library with changed function names or namespace go into /usr/local/lib.
Hence the wrong library is linked.

Comment: solution: after make; su; make install erase /usr/lib/mosquitto* in order that /usr/local/lib/mosquitto is used